# Kibana TERM Analysis Not showing the result using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just started Kibana TERM Analysis with Elasticsearch. when i Search 'Barak Obama' it shows in TERM Analysis different results like Barak(15),Obama(18) in separate Term. I want in Single Pharse like Barak Obama(30). where should i change in configuration.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your analyzer to do this with using shingle token filter.

- [What is an analyzer?](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html)
- [What is shingle token filter?](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html)

Comment: from where i can change the configuation in Kibana. plz

Comment: You cant change it in Kibana, it is elasticsearch config. And you should set it before indexing to make it effective.